# Dragula - how can I modify the width of the mirrored element?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using dragula and have run into an issue with the width and padding not being respected when the item is being dragged.

[See fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/f909t464/4/)

If I add `.gu-mirror {color: red;}` to the css, the text will change to red in the mirrored element when it is dragged, but if I add `.gu-mirror {width: 200px;}` that gets ignored. Any idea how I can change the width and padding of .gu-mirror?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `width: 200px !important;`, this should work.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you @DavidDomain